# Is there a kind of a/b test for checking CPU Usage?

Tags: cpu-usage, testing

Our team try to find a way to compare CPU and Memory usage between the current version and the new version. I found some answers.

(1) Using load balancer

By using load balancer, we can divide our servers into two group.
And by deploying different versions to them, we can test and measure them.
ref. https://cloud.google.com/architecture/application-deployment-and-testing-strategies

(2) My suggestions

I thought we don't need to divide servers if we can deploy new functions to randomly chosen server.
If it is possible, we can know the result of a/b tests by collecting the log of randomly chosen servers, separately. I think it is possible but fail to find this kind of thing in a/b test concept.

Could you give me advices about how I can a/b test for checking CPU Usage, or what (2) is called in the a/b test concept?

Comment: Typically you do [load and stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) with a simulated load  (before releasing your application to production) and simply compare the performance stats of a new version with your baseline results. Then once you do a (partial) roll-out in production you rely on your [systems monitoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor) (of system health and performance stats) to observe performance and if there is an improvement or rather a degradation

Comment: @HBruijn Yes, you're right. But I think it is hard to simulate the load in real, perfectly.  To mirror the load in real can be helpful but I think it is not good if the test servers and the release servers is connected to the same data base, because the test can have a bad impact to the release servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A/B testing from that link mentions includes business decisions on a statistically significant number of user interactions. For example, for a news publication, when presented headline A vs B, which one gets more clicks.

Unlikely you have a large number of backend instances where you can randomly sample their utilization metrics and get a good idea what is going on. Although sure, do statistics on your host monitoring data, see what the distribution is.

Also consider a canary test pattern and various flavors of rolling deployment. A change is introduced into one backend of the load balancer. When that does not set off monitoring alarms, including for CPU and memory, it is gradually deployed to the rest.

As these touch the production environment, the versions need to be verified compatible with the production database and APIs. Usually accomplished in a development environment, perhaps with mocked up fake data. These correctness tests are different from performance monitoring.

Unfortunately the performance characteristics in test is not really like production. It may be possible to replicate or backup restore production to a shadow staging environment, and get to test on real data. Even as a separate copy, this is a bit risky. There needs to be no production side-effects end users see. Production may have sensitive data, introducing compliance risks.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.
It is right to call it a/b test, the test for checking system resource? As you mentioned, a/b test looks only about a business decision. So it is hard to google the a/b test for system resource.

Comment: Also, rolling deployment can be helpful such as the canary but I want to test it before deployment. I want a lighter test, rather than the deployment. What we call this kind of test?

Comment: You may have a large enough instances to do a statistically significant A/B test. Ask a statistician.  A fundamental problem remains: test environments do not perform like production, but testing on real data is operationally challenging. Consider making small changes in production, however they are deployed. Isolating variables in a scientific method. And easier to undo for change control reasons.

Comment: I see. I appreciate your answer!